# How to get notified at the end of regex enumeration block?

Tags: ios, regex

I'm using the following code to manipulate my `str` string:

```
NSString *pattern = @"\\['(.*?)',(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\\]";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:nil];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:str
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
                         if (result != nil) 
                         {
                                 // do something with matched string
                         }
                 }];
```

How can I know when the block is in its last iteration so I can synch my program accordingly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the presence of blocks, which we often associate with asynchronous operations, these sorts of enumeration methods don't happen asynchronously. It runs synchronously. You should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can sync your program right after the regex:

```
[regex enumerateMatchesInString: ... ];
[self syncMyProgram];
```